# How can I restart footnote numbering every chapter?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Each chapter begins with a title 'Chapter 1; ...'  I've given every chapter title the same paragraph style.

Now, I have multiple footnotes in each chapter. I'm aware I can choose to number footnotes continuously throughout the document, or I can choose that numbering is reset every page or section. I would like the numbering to restart every chapter. Is there a way I can tell InDesign that every time it encounters the paragraph style 'Chapter title', it will mark it as a new section automatically, therefore restarting footnote numbering?

Thanks :)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I want to guess that it's possible to write a script to do this. Basically, loop through all the pages in the document. If the "Chapter title" paragraph style appears on the page, then "Start Section" = true; otherwise "Start Section" = false. I just don't know yet how to write that script.

Comment: See also, by the way, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/102477/how-can-i-automate-apply-master-and-start-section-selections